# Juntar 2 histogramas en un gráfico con ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Necesito juntar 2 histogramas que provienen de dos dataframes diferentes en un mismo gráfico con la función ggplot(). Quiero ver cómo los dos histogramas se solapan.
He intentado juntar los dos dataframes en uno pero tienen distinta longitud.

Os dejo un ejemplo de la situación en la que me encuentro:

```
ggplot(muestra1, aes(x=muestra1)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.25)+
  theme_classic()
ggplot(muestra2, aes(x=muestra2)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.25)+
  theme_classic()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Con datos independientes

```
ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(data = diamonds[diamonds$cut !='Premium',],  mapping = aes(carat), binwidth = 0.1, fill = "blue") +
  geom_histogram(data = diamonds[diamonds$cut =='Premium',],  mapping = aes(carat), binwidth = 0.1, fill = "yellow") +
  theme_classic()
```

Cada `geom_histogram()` debe tener su propio `data` y `mapping`, es conveniente que tengan el mismo `binwidth`, en algunos casos, puede ser conveniente agregar algo de `alpha` para poder ver el solapamiento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### 2. Con una sola fuente de datos

Esto es lo ideal, entiendo que has tenido problemas para hacerlo, que los datos tengan distinta longitud no debiera ser un problema, por que la unión debería ser "vertical"  y no "horizontal", mientras tengan o selecciones las mismas columnas deberías poder juntar ambas muestras con un `rbind`, en caso que logres hacerlo, la gráfica sería así:

```
ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(carat, fill = cut =='Premium')) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1, alpha = 0.5)
```

Tenemos un solo `geom_histogram()`, simplemente hemos "mapeado" una nueva dimensión estetica `fill` con la condición de que el diamante sea un corte `Premium`  o no, mediante: `fill = cut =='Premium'`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]